# Sympy - How to solve a system of equations in terms of x

Tags: python, sympy, substitution, solver, symbolic-math

I want to solve a system of equations with multiple variables.
The solution I'm looking for is in this form `y = f(z)`.

The problem is: sympy won't solve completely my equations.

Here's a small example to illustrate my problem.

```py
x = sympy.symbols("x", real=True)
y = sympy.symbols("y", real=True)
z = sympy.symbols("z", real=True)

eq0 = y - x**2
eq1 = x - z + 4

system = [eq0, eq1]
sympy.solve(system, y)[y]
```

This code produces `y = x^2`, which is mathematically correct, but not what I wanted.
What I want to see is my system solved like this `y = f(z)` therefore (`y = (z - 4)^2`).

Is there a way to define input and output in sympy's solvers?
Something like this:

```py
sympy.solve(equations, input=z, ouptut=y)
```

---

Small note about **substitution**:
In this naive example, I could substitute the intermediate variable `x` with `z+4` to solve the problem.
That said, I would prefer an alternative solution because, in my real problem, my system has 36 equations and substituting would be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `solve` the variables to solve for.

```
eq0 = y - x**2
eq1 = x - z + 4
system = [eq0, eq1]
# solve your system of equation for x, y
solve(system, [x, y], dict=True)[0][y]
# out: (z - 4)^2
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `solve()` function expects me to pass all the intermediate variables?

Comment: Because in my system I have 36 equations and 36 variables. If `solve` start trying to a very single one of them, it will take hours to produce things I don't need.

Comment: Give it a try and post your results if it actually hangs. It can solve larger in a short time. It all depends on the equations.

Comment: Hi Smichr !
After 30min the equation has not been solved.
I'm trying to think of a solution.

Comment: Post your equations. Try `solve(eqs, syms, manual=True, check=False, simplify=False)`.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I needed to extinguish a fire somewhere else.

Comment: Sadly, I can't share the equations, but the problem stays the same. 
Defining input/output seems like such a no-brainer feature. I wonder if I'm missing something.